# Selenium + remote/local + testng + maven = war or jar?

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, selenium, jenkins

I need to create a single maven project to execute selenium tests remotely or localy depending on testng.xml.

This is my current idea

test execution (depending on testng.xml will run test localy on a certain browser or on remove server):

```
mvn -Drun-script test
```

server execution:

```
mvn Dport=4444 run
```

The question how should I run the server part? Should I package as jar and use exec:java or war with tomcat plugin t7:run? Tests will be executed continiously by Jenkins.

P.S. I'm not quite sure whether is a proper good architure at all. I'm new to UI testing. But need to have two maven commands and testng.xml with configs as an input.

Comment: If you use Selenium I suppose it's a web app developped with a JavaEE technology, so you probably have to deploy the war on a servlet container (as Tomcat, GlassFish or Jetty). In case of a hard-coded server using java socket, you just have to run the jar.

Comment: I use selenium-server so It has embedded servlet container